# Find and delete document inside nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling to delete element inside nested arrray in mongoDB.

Lets say I have this schema:

```
var question = new Schema({
  problem: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  multipleChoices: [{
    type: String,
    required: true
  }],
  correctAnswer: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});

var testCategorySchema = new Schema({
  category: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  tests: [{
    version: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    questions: [question]
  }]
});
```

For example I have instance of that schema like this:

```
{
  category: "Math",
  tests: [
    {
      _id : ObjectId("580859310a0d4b40ac1c6034"),
      version: "1A",
      questions: [
         {
           problem: "blablabla",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ],
           correctAnswer: 1
         },
         {
           problem: "blibliblibli",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ]
           correctAnswer: 1
         }
      ]
    },
    {
      _id : ObjectId("580859310a0d4r40ax1c5034"),
      version: "1B",
      questions: [
         {
           problem: "auauauauau",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ]
           correctAnswer: 1
         },
         {
           problem: "blibliblibli",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ]
           correctAnswer: 1
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For example, how can I delete problem: "blablabla" in category math and version 1A using mongooseJS?

I already to delete problem in math category and version 1A using this code:

```
TestCategory
    .findOne(
      {
        category: req.params.testCategory,
        'tests.version': req.params.testVersion
      },
      {
        'tests.version.$': 1
      }
    )
    .then(function(testVersion) {
      res.send(testVersion);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
    });
```

For example I search math category and version 1A, the result from that code is like this:

```
_id: "580859190a0d4b40ac1c6033",
tests: [
    {
      _id : ObjectId("580859310a0d4b40ac1c6034"),
      version: "1A",
      questions: [
         {
           problem: "blablabla",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ],
           correctAnswer: 1
         },
         {
           problem: "blibliblibli",
           multiplechoices: [
            "bla bla", "blb blb", "blc blc"
          ]
           correctAnswer: 1
         }
      ]
    }
]
```

The result already filtered, so only version 1A is displayed (although categoryId is still displayed). Now I am confused how to delete the question in proper and good way.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet to achieve this?

Comment: I already tried something, let me updated the question

Comment: @Shrabanee updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `update` with the positional operator [`$`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/update/positional/) in order to update the correct test and then use [`$pull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to remove the question:

```
TestCategory.update(
    {
        category: 'Math',
        'tests.version': '1A'
    },
    {
        $pull: {
            'tests.$.questions': { problem: 'blablabla' }
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: `$pull: {
            'tests.$.questions': { problem: 'blablabla' }
        }`

Comment: How can I delete it by question / problem id?

Comment: you asked to remove by the `problem` value. in your schema and example doc you don't have a problem id, so how you want to delete by them? if you did have id per question, just replace the `problem` with `_id` in the code above, I don't think I need to explain this. you need to think and try by yourself before asking these kind of questions.

Comment: yess I have id, because in mongoose question is child schema. I did typo when change problem to id (typo -> iid). Now it's work. Thank you dude

Comment: you can also vote up and not only accept the answer :)

Comment: sorry, because of that typo I ask "How can I delete it by question / problem id? ". Cause after I failed, I think the method is different when I want to update by ID